# Wear OS complication .setTapAction for calling an activity

Tags: android, kotlin, wear-os, android-wear-complication

I am trying to put `setTapAction` of my complication to call the activity, but it’s not working whenever I tap it does not do anything just a ripple effect, my code is below.

```kotlin
class CustomComplication : SuspendingComplicationDataSourceService() {

    // Retrieves your data, in this case, we grab an incrementing number from Datastore.
    val prefs = getSharedPreferences("MY_PREFS_NAME", MODE_PRIVATE)
    val tempF = prefs.getString("tempF", "") //"No name defined" is the default value.

    val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java).apply {
        component = ComponentName(this@CustomComplication, MainActivity::class.java)
    }
    val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)

    override fun getPreviewData(type: ComplicationType): ComplicationData? {
        if (type != ComplicationType.SHORT_TEXT) {
            return null
        }
        return createComplicationData(tempF.toString(), "Monday")
    }

    override suspend fun onComplicationRequest(request: ComplicationRequest): ComplicationData? {

        Log.d("BABT", "onComplicationRequest() id: ${request.complicationInstanceId}")

        return when (request.complicationType) {

            ComplicationType.SHORT_TEXT -> ShortTextComplicationData.Builder(
                text = PlainComplicationText.Builder(text = tempF.toString()).build(),
                contentDescription = PlainComplicationText
                    .Builder(text = "Short Text version of Number.").build(),
          ).setMonochromaticImage(
           MonochromaticImage.Builder(
                        image = Icon.createWithResource(this, R.drawable.iconforbody),
                    ).build(),
                )
               .setTapAction(pendingIntent)
               .build()

            else -> {
                if (Log.isLoggable("BABT", Log.WARN)) {
                    Log.w("BABT", "Unexpected complication type ${request.complicationType}")
                }
                null
            }
        }
    }

    private fun createComplicationData(text: String, contentDescription: String) =
        ShortTextComplicationData.Builder(
            text = PlainComplicationText.Builder(text).build(),
            contentDescription = PlainComplicationText.Builder(contentDescription).build()
        ).build()
}
```

I tried above code but it is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting in Android 12, you have to use [`PendingIntent#FLAG_IMMUTABLE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent#FLAG_IMMUTABLE) or [`PendingIntent#FLAG_MUTABLE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent#FLAG_MUTABLE), it's strongly recommended to use [`PendingIntent#FLAG_IMMUTABLE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent#FLAG_IMMUTABLE):

```kotlin
val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)
```